# Is there any way we can replace a value in Matrix with NA using apply function only

Tags: r, apply, na

I want to replace wherever value is greater than 8 to NA using only "Apply" function in a matrix of 1 to 20

```
m <- matrix(c(1:10, 11:20), nrow = 5, ncol = 4)
```

I have tried `apply(m, 1:2, function(x) x = replace_na(x, 0))`
after making values zero (whichever was greater than 8)
Second I tried is

```
apply(m, 1:2, function(x) is.na(x) <- !x)
```

Third I tried is

```
apply(m, 1:2, function(x) replace_na(x>8))
```

Matrix should have all the values as NA from 9 to 20

Comment: Rowwise or column wise, or both? Try `apply(m, 1,function(x) ifelse(x>8,NA,x))`

Comment: You don't need `apply` - you can just do `m[m>8] <- NA`

Comment: thanks a ton! this worked-apply(m, 1:2,function(x) ifelse(x>8,NA,x))

Answer (score 4):

We can assign with `is.na`

```
`is.na<-`(m, m > 8)
```